# Move value under std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, memory-management, unique-ptr

I have a function `foo(T value)`, where `T` is move-only. I want to (for some reasons) allocate `value` of type `T` and call `foo`.

Can I do it like this?

```
{
  std::unique_ptr<T> ptr = make_unique<T>(T());
  foo(std::move(*ptr));
}
```

If it's not clear: I want to get rid of `new` and `delete` in this code:

```
void ServeForever(uint16_t port) {
  Acceptor acceptor;
  acceptor.BindTo(port).ExpectOk();
  acceptor.Listen().ExpectOk();
  while (true) {
    Socket* socket = new Socket(acceptor.Accept());
    Spawn([socket]() {
      HandleClient(std::move(*socket));
      delete socket;
    }).Detach();
  }
}
```

Comment: why is `socket` not created inside the lambda? seems like it is exclusively used there

Comment: You should at least show the function that is "move-only", since you're asking a question about move semantics, it's entirely possible you are confused about the function itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to involve pointers at all:

```
void HandleCLient(Socket socket){
    //...
}

//...

while (true) {
    //Construct in-place
    Spawn([s=Socket(acceptor.Accept)]() mutable
    {
      HandleClient(std::move(s));
    }).Detach();
}
```

Thanks @rafix07 for pointing out the need for adding `mutable`.